# How can I filter multiple columns with dplyr using string matching for the column name?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm curious about what would be a more succinct way to achieve this:

```
nyc_crashes %>% filter(
  `NUMBER OF PERSONS INJURED`     >= 1 |
  `NUMBER OF PERSONS KILLED`      >= 1 |
  `NUMBER OF PEDESTRIANS INJURED` >= 1 |
  `NUMBER OF PEDESTRIANS KILLED`  >= 1 |
  `NUMBER OF CYCLIST INJURED`     >= 1 |
  `NUMBER OF CYCLIST KILLED`      >= 1 |
  `NUMBER OF MOTORIST INJURED`    >= 1 |
  `NUMBER OF MOTORIST KILLED`     >= 1
)
```

Could I use string matching for "INJURED | KILLED" and not have to write a different condition for each column name?

Comment: These might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/60270550/786542 & https://stackoverflow.com/a/60269597/786542

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do that using `filter_at` with `ends_with`.

```
library(dplyr)
nyc_crashes %>%
  # Select columns that end with KILLED or INJURED
  filter_at(vars(c(ends_with("KILLED"),ends_with("INJURED"))), 
            # Keep rows where any of these variables is >= 1 
                          any_vars(. >= 1))
```

Comment: is there a way to do this same thing but to keep rows where variable takes on specific values? For instance, instead of just >=1, where they equal 1, 3, or 99?

Comment: You could use `any_vars(. %in% c(1, 3, 99)))`